# Python Selenium Chrome Webdrives closes unexpectedly after the execution of program

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I have updated the version of chrome and accordingly webdriver. The chrome closes automatically after the execution of the last line. It was a simple code to open a chrome driver and click the links. After I run in command prompt it generated the error message ***"failed to load pepper module from internal-not-yet-present (error 126)"***.

Due to which the Pycharm generates the error **"Oserror:[winerror 6] The handle is invalid"**

Can anyone please suggest the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this (quite) a while ago. In my case an Adobe Flash Player update was required for Chrome: in `chrome://components` find the Adobe Flash Player entry and check for updates.

Alternatively, disable extensions:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: I updated all the components, but it did not work for me. Are there any other options?

Comment: As I can't reproduce the issue now it's a bit tricky, but I added one  idea for you to try..

Comment: There is not much difference in the results, after the addition of the code. I had tried it previously it had worked fine, I am unable to know why this occured,